# How do I call a method from one class in another?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am trying to call the `statemotOfPhilosopy` in my other class.

There are two classes:

First class `SetUpSite`:

```
package setupsite;

public class SetUpSite {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        statementOfPhilosophy();
    }

    public static void statementOfPhilosophy() {
        System.out.println("Even Handlers Incoroporated is");
        System.out.println("dedicated to making your event");
        System.out.println("a most memorable one.");
    }
}
```

And the second class `CallingMethods`:

```
package callingmethods;

public class CallingMethods {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Calling method from another class:");
        SetUpSite.statementOfPhilosophy(); //Error here at the SetUpSite
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error ? did you import `SetUpSite` ?

Comment: Did you import the SetUpSite class: `import setupsite.SetUpSite`

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You forgot to add the import statement add this line**::     `import setupsite.SetUpSite`

---

```
    package setupsite;
    public class SetUpSite {        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            statementOfPhilosophy();
        }
        public static void statementOfPhilosophy()
        {
            System.out.println("Even Handlers Incoroporated is");
            System.out.println("dedicated to making your event");
            System.out.println("a most memorable one.");
        }         
    }
```

---

```
package callingmethods;
import setupsite.SetUpSite

public class CallingMethods {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Calling method from another class:");
            SetUpSite.statementOfPhilosophy(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must import the `setupsite` package.
Your code will be look like :

```
package callingmethods;
import setupsite.SetUpSite;

public class CallingMethods {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Calling method from another class:");
            SetUpSite.statementOfPhilosophy(); //Error here at the SetUpSite
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to `import setupsite` package here:

```
import setupsite;
```

then try.